# How do I get more pet chests in Fallout Shelter?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I have Fallout Shelter on two devices- PC and phone. At some point on both of these devices I received a free kind of Lunchbox which gave me one pet. This was before I got 13 people in my Vault. No matter how many game files I start, I have only ever received one on each device. How does this work? What are my chances, if any, of getting a second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Fallout Shelter save games are not particularly robust against editing.  It is actually JSON formatted.

You can also just edit in more Pet Carriers using [Fallout Shelter Save Editor](https://robot9706.github.io/FSSE/)

Comment: Thank you. I will be sure to hack *cough* USE the tool you have recommended.

Answer (score 1):

The only ways to get the pet carriers are limited.

1. You get one(as mentioned in the question) from a lunchbox
2. Missions, it is possible to get lunchboxes, Mr. Handies, and, yes, **Pet Carriers**
3. And, of course, buying the pet carries